# Image::Magick Install Error 127

Tags: perl, ubuntu, makefile, imagemagick, cpan

When I try to install Image::Magick via CPAN on an Ubuntu system, I get an 127 error. I have no idea what is going wrong. Below is the text of what I get:

```
cpan[1]> install Image::Magick
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 15 Nov 2013 21:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Image::Magick'
Running make for J/JC/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/J/JC/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

  CPAN.pm: Building J/JC/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...

Looks good

Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lMagickCore-6.Q16

Generating a Unix-style Makefile

Writing Makefile for Image::Magick

Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

cp Magick.pm blib/lib/Image/Magick.pm

AutoSplitting blib/lib/Image/Magick.pm (blib/lib/auto/Image/Magick)

/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl/5.14/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl/5.14/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  Magick.xs > Magick.xsc && mv Magick.xsc Magick.c

cc -c  -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/usr/include/ImageMagick-6" -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -O2 -g   -DVERSION=\"6.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"6.86\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE"  -D_LARGE_FILES=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H Magick.c

/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found

make: *** [Magick.o] Error 127

  JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK

Running make test

  Can't test without successful make

Running make install

  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

Failed during this command:

 JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz               : make NO
```

Comment: You should try google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027302/imagemagick-install-error-127

Comment: @RUJordan: did you mean to link to some *other* question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
```

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

before installing from CPAN.

Do you need the newest version?  You should be able to get an only slightly older version with apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try installing ImageMagick for Perl on Ubuntuas per below, and not via Cpan:

```
sudo apt-get install perlmagick
```